# Click and update on android widget

Tags: java, android, widget

I made an widget which have the image and show the time. howerver , the time cannot update.so I try to implement that the time will be updated when user click on the widget.
I find some tutorial said that using setOnClickPendingIntent can do this but my code not work.

Any solutions can let the widget update the time onClick or Auto Updating?

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            int appWidgetId) {


    CharSequence widgetText =   DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());;
    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageView, pendingIntent);

    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.editText2, widgetText);

    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, updateViews);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change you `PendingIntent` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent()
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUES, values)
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class));
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: i want to update the R.id.editText2 to the time ( CharSequence widgetText)

Comment: so i change intent.putExtra(EXTRA_VALUES, values) to         intent.putExtra(R.id.editText2, widgetText); , but it not works

Comment: `putExtra()` store as Key Values pair So key will be always `String`